Flutter wrap with elements take full width
i want to make a layout like image below, i want a layout that be wrap not grid(i don't want all of my elements be same width), but i want the elements stretch and take whole width, how can i achieve something like this in flutter

this doesn't do what i want
class CategoryList extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Wrap Example')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Wrap(
          spacing: 8.0, // Horizontal space between items
          runSpacing: 8.0, // Vertical space between lines
          children: categories.map((label) => CategoryCard(label)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Try using https://pub.dev/packages/flex_list.

@SpiritCrusher Amazing, thank you!

If I understand your problem correctly, you can Wrap the Category Card inside of a Expand() Widget.

no, i tried that
